# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/FontMapper

Tags: java

Recently we upgrade itext jar from `2.1.7` to `itextpdf-5.4.2.jar` but getting below nested exception is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/pdf/FontMapper exception
```

and we are using jasper reports `4.7.0` in that they are using below package

```
com/lowagie/text/pdf/FontMapper
```

only that's why it causes a problem. How to resolve this issue. (it's mandatory we have to upgrade itext jar at any cost)

Comment: You'll need to upgrade Jasper as well. Jasper 6, I think, supports itext > 2.1.7.

Comment: tried with jasper reports-6.0.jar but still getting same